# Why can't I edit page layouts in Google Chrome in Winter 14?

Tags: customization, bug, winter14, platform-bug, chrome

When using the latest version of Google Chrome, the Layout Editor palette is empty, so we cannot add fields, related lists, buttons, or any other objects to the page. No console errors are reported. Will attach a screenshot for this issue. Other browsers such as Safari and Firefox are working correctly. No information appears in "Salesforce Known Issues" for this problem.

This is really more of a question to see if anyone else is experiencing this. I've included a screenshot of the issue to see if anyone else can add their experiences here. Is there any workaround, besides the usual "use a different browser" answer? The editor works just fine in Firefox, Internet Explorer, and Safari, all on the same computer.

I've also submitted case 09807031 to salesforce.com, in case anyone with any inside connections wants to look into this.

[image: Chrome Bug-Winter 14]

### Update #1

Just tried this in Incognito mode, with extensions disabled, and the result is the same.

Comment: I just updated my chrome to Version 30.0.1599.101 m,
No such error Sorry

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you using? The beta version seems to have several rendering issues.

Comment: No issues. Tried to reproduce with GC 30.0.1599.69 on Macbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to disable all extensions or go into incognito mode and see if that helps. I had a different issue where the extensions I was using cause a conflict with a few pages. I agree with @TimChadwick I just tested with Chrome Version 30.0.1599.101 and do not have an issue.

Below is the HTML inside the left hand nav of the layout editor

```
<div id="troughSelector" style="overflow: auto; width: 136px; height: 130px;">
<ul>
    <li class="selected">
        <div class="selectorItem" id="troughCategory__Field">Fields</div>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <div class="selectorItem" id="troughCategory__Button">Buttons</div>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <div class="selectorItem" id="troughCategory__CustomLink">Custom Links</div>
    </li>
```

Comment: Occurs in Incognito mode as well, with and without extensions enabled.

Comment: Interesting? Try comparing the page source of the fields window in Chrome vs the page source in the browsers that work. I'm curious to see if its being loaded at all or if its just hidden? (js maybe?) Also, if you run a debug using Chrome vs browsers that work do you see any errors/differences?

Comment: No errors in console. The only statistically interesting difference between the pages generated is that the CSS files use a directory called /base/ in Firefox, and /gc/ in Chrome.

Comment: Are you having this across all objects in your org when using Chrome? Is the html <ul><li> code in the 'Fields Buttons, Custom links..." section. I've updated my answer to show the code I have in that section for reference.

Comment: Mine is missing two elements: `<div id="troughSelector" style="overflow: auto; width: 136px; height: 130px;"><ul><li class="selected"><div class="selectorItem" id="troughCategory__values"></div></li></ul></div>`

Comment: Weird? I'm definitely stumped on this one. One last stab in the dark. Have you tried Chrome from another computer?

Comment: I actually just did a short while ago, was going to post results here... same Chrome version, same 64-bit Windows, same amount of system memory, virtual memory, extensions, synced to same Google account, but different CPU vendors and slightly different speeds... and it works fine. So, I've narrowed it down to just this one computer, but I don't know why, as the two computers are nearly identical except one is a laptop the other a custom-modified tower (the tower works fine).

Comment: My anti-virus (AVG) updated the same time as Winter 14 came out, and so I mistakenly blamed salesforce.com. The culprit was my anti-virus filtering out some content that was necessary for the page to work. It appears to be related to the "safe browsing plugin" for Chrome, since my other browsers were unaffected. After getting rid of the extension and reinstalling Chrome, everything works now.

Comment: An antivirus plugin did not even cross my mind as a possible culprit! Its amazing, and a little scary that antivirus plugins can affect web pages in such a way that crucial content is not displayed. Gone are the days where only browser compatibility gave devs the biggest headaches. I'm glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing this same issue, as well as certain visualforce pages in Salesforce not fully loading (it gets stuck 50% through loading the page).

But I definitely am still experiencing this issue with Page layouts. I need to go to firefox every time.